# mySQLi select and update in the same time

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table `numbers` with 3 columns `id`, `number` and `ts`

I want to randomly select 10 records where ts is NULL to fetch them and in the same time update their `ts` with current timestamp so that the next select I don't get the same results, and to know when every `number` has been selected.

```
$ts = time();

$query = 'UPDATE numbers SET ts = ' . $ts . ' WHERE number IN (SELECT number FROM (SELECT number FROM numbers WHERE ts IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10) AS t)';
if (!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($number);
$stmt->store_result();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $number . '<br>';
}
```

Here I dont need any bind_param() because there is no external input.

Now, this query returns

> **Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in...**

Comment: The result of an UPDATE query is either TRUE or FALSE so there is no result to bind to

Comment: You're right, how to get the result from the SELECT?

Comment: There is no SELECT, the select is a sub query and therefore is used only be the main query to limit what the main UPDATE query does

Comment: If you want to know which rows got updated, you will have to split that process into a SELECT query and an UPDATE query and build the IN list manually from the SELECT queries results

Answer (score 0):

Just use this query

```
$query = 'UPDATE numbers SET ts = " . $ts . " WHERE number IN (SELECT number FROM numbers WHERE
          ts IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10)';
```

Modification:-
I just **remove extra select** statement and correct **quotes** .

Answer (score 0):

I found it, update, then select the updated rows where ts = $ts

```
$ts = time();

$query = 'UPDATE numbers SET ts = ' . $ts . ' WHERE ts IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10';
if (!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

$query = 'SELECT number FROM numbers WHERE ts = ' . $ts . ' ORDER BY RAND()';
if (!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($number);
$stmt->store_result();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $number . '<br>';
}
```